# Database fields from a stored procedure in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure in SQL server 2008 as follow:

```
if something

select 
x, y
... from table 1

 else 

select
a, b
... from table 2
```

The database field in Crytal Reports is not showing me `a` and `b` from the second statement but only `x`, `y`.

How to proceed in Crystal Report in order to have all these fields ?

Comment: something is not a precise word I agree ! What I need is that depending on the value of IF, the first select statement or the second is chosen.  These statements are two completely different requests. 
I’m new to Crystal Report and I was wondering if it was a misunderstanding how Crystal works before merging my two statements!

Comment: Is `something` a parameter you are passing to the stored procedure from Crystal Reports?  If so, datatype and values are you passing in?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `something`?  If that is how your procedure is written, your report will only ever return either `x` and `y` or `a` and `b` depending on what your `IF` statement returns.

If you want all of them returned, you need to edit your question with your procedure, and show your data strutures.  I strongly suspect you'll need some combination of `SELECT CASE` and/or `UNION` to join your tables and conditionally return columns.